# Reading from a file and outputting to sockets

Tags: c, file, sockets, http, file-io

so i am working on a method that reads in a file and outputs its contents to a socket.

However, instead of my simple index.html file my browser shows this:

```
#öÇdÿ GÊdÿ(˜ÊdÿÎ+Yÿ@0Çdÿ  ŸÊdÿÐÎ+YÿÍ×ÇdÿHÌÊdÿèÌÊdÿ@Î+YÿlñÇdÿ ŸÊdÿ8öŒÿ¶¢ð‘ÿÎ+YÿòXÈdÿ GÊdÿ ŸÊdÿØ¾Êdÿâ@”ÐÎ+YÿŠÈdÿ Ð+Yÿ ŸÊdÿ ²Êdÿâ@”Ï+YÿŠÈdÿ Ð+YØ¾Êdÿ°0ÊdÿØ¾Êdÿ°0Êdÿ°0Êdÿ ŸÊdÿ`Ï+Yÿ¡Èdÿ°0Êdÿ ŸÊdÿ°0Êdÿâ@” Ð+Yÿ°Ï+YÿcbÈdÿ Ð+Yÿ¼À‡¨Qµpÿ8A”ë@”p0” ŸÊdÿPÐ+Yÿ¨ ®ÿ «ª2Ð+Yÿ©$®ÿ„Ð+Yÿ€Ð+Yÿ|Ð+Yÿ†Æuÿ€¸†Æuÿ€wÈ` †ÆuÿèƒÆuÿ yÆuÿ†Æuÿ Ð+Yÿó(®ÿU«""öèƒÆu` ƒƒèƒÆuÿ/”ÐÐ+YÿÕ;$ŒÿèƒÆuÿ/”ôÆuÿÐÑ+Yÿ$Œÿ †ÆuÿU«""ö@Ð+Yÿin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/locusr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin0àÑ+YÿàÐ+Yÿusername
```

**Code:**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <errno.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PORT 8080
#define PROTOCOL 0
#define BACKLOG 10
#define BUFLEN 1500



void serve_file(int sock, char* filename) 
{ 
  char buffer[1024]; 
  FILE *file;

  // Open file for reading
  file = fopen(filename, "rb");
  if (!file) {
    printf("Error: can't open file for reading");
    return;
  }

  if ((fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file)) != NULL) {
    int sent = send(sock, &buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);
    if (sent == -1) {
      printf("Error: send to socket failed\n");
      printf("Error code: %s\n", strerror(errno));      
    }
  } else {
    printf("Error: could not read file contents");
    return;
  }

  // Bye
  fclose(file);
} 

int main()
{
  int fd;
  int connfd;

  // For bind()
  struct sockaddr_in addr; 

  // For accept()
  struct sockaddr_in cliaddr; 
  socklen_t cliaddrlen = sizeof(cliaddr);

  // For reading and writing
  ssize_t i;
  ssize_t rcount;
  char buffer[BUFLEN];

  // Open a socket
  fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, PROTOCOL);
  if (fd == -1) {
    printf("Error: unable to open a socket\n");
    printf("Error code: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  // Create an address
  //memset(&addr, 0, sizeof addr);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

  int yes = 1;
  if ( setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1 )
  {
      perror("setsockopt");
  }

  if ((bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr))) == -1) {
    printf("Error: unable to bind\n");
    printf("Error code: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  // Listen for connections
  if ((listen(fd, BACKLOG)) == -1) {
    printf("Error: unable to listen for connections\n");
    printf("Error code: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  // Accept connections
  connfd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &cliaddrlen);
  if (connfd == -1) {
    printf("Error: unable to accept connections\n");
    printf("Error code: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  // Read data
  rcount = read(connfd, buffer, BUFLEN);
  if (rcount == -1) {    
    printf("Error: unable to accept connections\n");
    printf("Error code: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < rcount; i++) {
    printf("%c", buffer[i]);
  }

  //write(connfd, buffer, rcount);
  serve_file(connfd, "index.html");


  // Bye
  close(connfd);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use the http protocol if you wish to see it from the browser.

Comment: huh? I am seeing it in the browser. I believe there is something wrong with the encoding.

Comment: Your send should be using buffer instead of &buffer

Comment: Do you want the contents of the file or to display the file as a web page?  If it is the latter then you need to send the http header first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
int sent = send(sock, &buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);
```

to be

```
int sent = send(sock, &buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
```

to only send what `fgets()` did read.

---

Moreover, be aware, that [`send()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) does not necessarly sends as much bytes as it was told to do.

To make sure everthing is sent, test [`send()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html)'s result to see how much actual was send and loop around `send()` to send the rest.

From [`man send`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html):

> On success, these calls return the number of bytes sent.

---

Also `send()` returns `ssize_t` not `int`.

---

Also^2 it's at least:

```
int main(void)
```

---

Also^3: The code misses to `fclose()` the file in case `fgets()` returned `NULL`, what it defintily will do when it reached EOF.

---

Also^Finally: `serve_file()` ever only reads (and sends) the file's first line.

To fix this change this

```
  if ((fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file)) != NULL) {
    int sent = send(sock, &buffer, sizeof buffer, 0);
    if (sent == -1) {
      printf("Error: send to socket failed\n");
      printf("Error code: %s\n", strerror(errno));      
    }
  } else {
    printf("Error: could not read file contents");
    return;
  }
```

to look like this

```
  while ((fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file)) != NULL) {
    ...
  }

  if (ferror(file)) {
    printf("Error reading file contents.");
  }
```

Comment: Ok, i only get a blank screen now :/

Comment: @chuckfinley: You definitly have to test the result of `send()` to see how much data was sent.

Comment: I get 14 bytes. Views source shows "<html ng-app>" - which is the first line of the document.

Comment: So basically i have to do a while loop and send() stuff out until bytes read == strlen(buffer) ?

Comment: @chuckfinley: Yes. Loop around `send()`, adding up how much bytes went out, and start resending the buffer's content from that index on, up until the bytes sent summed up to the value you initial wanted to send, that is the number of bytes read by `fgets()`. Take care not to send anything twice.

Comment: "*... until bytes read == strlen(buffer)*" you meant to write: "*... until bytes send == strlen(buffer)*" didn't you?

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant, sorry. Apparently strlen(buffer) is 14 as well - there is something wrong with my reading method.

Comment: No, the read-loop is ok, besides the fact that the file won't get closed. Trace through your code using a debugger, or at least add some debug-`fprintf(stderr, ...` to get enlightend what really happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48801/discussion-between-chuckfinley-and-alk)